# Why is foldl signature is a pipeline instead of a tuple like type in SML?

Tags: smlnj

I do not understand why the signature of `foldl` is like that.

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Tue Aug  8 23:21:20 2017]
- foldl;
val it = fn : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

In particular, the arrows `->` should've been asterisk `*` like the following:

```
val it = fn : ('a * 'b -> 'b) * 'b * 'a list -> 'b
```

And the reason is because `foldl` takes the following:

1. Function `('a * 'b -> 'b)` that compares & returns one of two strings; assuming `acc` is 'b, thus, returning `acc`
2. `acc` & `'a list` to compare them.
3. Finally, returning the base 'b which is `acc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` entails it to be a tuple, and which necessitates that all the components of the tuple will have to be provided... `->` entails `currying`, which allows `partial application`. Both are 2 different semantics.

Also, it is interesting that you write
`...foldl takes a function that compares two strings...`.

`foldl` is generic and quite polymorphic, so why will it work only with `string`. A particular `function application` may work over `string` data, but not the `function definition` itself.

Comment: the `string` here was just an example of usage but thanks anyways for the answer.